# Загрузка изображения в Django

Tags: python, django

Ребят, подскажите, пожалуйста. Только начал учить Django и применять на практике.

Пытаюсь сделать так, что бы через админку можно было загрузить файлы в коде. Использовал upload_to. Написано в книге, что он загружает по статистическому пути (извиняюсь за белиберду). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В браузере выдает следующую ошибку:

> Exception Value: no such column: products_product.name

Comment: Какое отношение имеет несуществующая колонка name к загрузке файлов("no such column: products_product.name")? Вы обновляли связь django c базой после обновления?

Comment: Не прикладывайте код картинками, выложите проблемный на ваш взгляд как текст. По изображениям невозможно вести поиск, код с картинки невозможно скопировать себе, на картинке невозможно что-либо разглядеть.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку...действительно забыл сделать миграцию БД